# C# code arrangement tool recommendations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been looking for a great code arrangement tool for c#. It would be nice to have something that can arrange code into regions etc and put items into alphabetical order.

I have tried NArrange and while it works well it is a little clunky in the integration department and did give us issues mixing up xml comments.

Any recommendations free > paid would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use [XArrange 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/43a29648-409a-4225-988c-a64d01eb8386), it is free.
Method, property etc sorting is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not free(sorry), but take a look to [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: Cheers, yes actually running an evaluation at the moment for general re-factoring, wasn't aware it had that functionality. Probilly because the code had already been NArranged, ill try it out thanks.

Comment: +1 vote for the Resharper. I would say that it is (and maybe other similar products) worth of money for all professional C# developers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [regionerate](http://www.regionerate.net/regionerate/)

Answer (score 0):

I use fxCop along with the r# plugin and find it pretty ok

Answer (score 0):

What is the benefit of ordering methods alphabetically? Shouldn't they rather be ordered logically according to the problem they solve. Generally I believe that if you have so many methods in a class/file that you think it makes sense to order them alphabetically your model is wrong, and it would be more beneficial to split your code in more classes/files.

With regards to regions, I have a hard time seeing what the benefit is. I recommend that you read Jeff Atwood's (CTO of stackoverflow) [blog post on regions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html).

Comment: By items alphabetically I was thinking more fields / properties. As right as you are sometimes you do get BIG classes that need making sense of (thinking old code that you cannot afford to refactor but would love to smarten up for free)